# Json content within json content

Tags: php, javascript, json

I am currently working on a php/html/javascript project and am doing ajax post to a php script which returns json encoded data. Within this json encoded there is some more json encoded data.

Below is how I am json encoding the data

```
$category[0]['Category'] = "Category 1";
    $category[1]['Category'] = "Category 2";

    $article['Date'] = "11/11/2012 22:42:00";
    $article['Title'] = "This is the title";
    $article['Subtitle'] = "This is the subtitle";
    $article['Content'] = "This is the content1";
    $article['ViaName'] = "SomeSite";
    $article['ViaAddress'] = "http://localhost";
    $article['SourceName'] = "N/A";
    $article['SourceAddress'] = "N/A";
    $article['categories'] = json_encode($category);

    echo json_encode($article);
```

The $article that gets json encoded I can access fine when it is returned to the javascript using json.Title, json.Subtitle etc.

But when I try and get the categories it doesn't work.

I've tried using json.categories and this prints out the following:

```
[{"Category":"Category 1"},{"Category":"Category 2"}]
```

This looks like its working so when I try and access each individual part it then doesn't work. I've tried `json.categories[0].Category` and `json.categories.Category[0]` but it keeps on coming up an undefined.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: The answers below show how you _should_ fix this, but hypothetically if you had to do it from JavaScript for some reason you could say `json.categories = JSON.parse(json.categories)` and _then_ access `json.categories[0].Category` (because as mentioned in the accepted answer `json.categories` is a string so you have to parse it before you can use it as an array of objects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you encode an array with `json_encode` you got a `string`. So, in your case, `json.categories` is a string and not an array.

However, `json_encode` (and decode) is recursive.

So you should use simply

```
$article['categories'] = $category;
```

without encode again.

Answer (score 0):

No wait. You are json encoding an array into a value of another array which will be encoded aswell. You should just do:

```
$article['categories'] = $category;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your category json array to article array to access with article variable

```
$article['categories'] = $category;
```